# wordpress memory issue ec2 instance

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, amazon-ec2

I have installed WordPress on my t2.micro instance. WordPress is working fine with my existing theme, but when I install a new theme and activate it, my instance memory goes too high and ultimately my instance doesn't respond any more and the site goes down and I get

> bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory

I have to restart instance again. I tried many themes but am getting the same issue again and again.

I have set php memory Limit `128M` in php.ini and `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');` in wp-config.php.

My htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I need some expert suggestion to help me out.

Comment: You likely need to limit the number of Apache processes and MySQL's RAM usage.

Comment: i used nginx and apache both getting same issue with both web server.

Comment: Which process is causing the error? As @ceejayoz says, it could be MySQL

Comment: No it is not mysql, actually php-fpm is there, when i change theme it consume a lot memory , i have reduced process for php-fpm then when site is running very slow , i have created testing environment with 1GB RAM free instance over AWS